# Squirrel.Windows and Octopus Deploy: Error while signing application

Tags: code-signing, octopus-deploy, authenticode, squirrel.windows

I am trying to sign my application using the *-n* option on *Squirrel.exe* from Octopus *deploy.ps1* script I keep getting the following error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Failed to sign, command invoked was: 'C:\OctopusTentacle\Applications\Test\Tridoo.Client\1.5.0-automate-deploym0024\tools\Squirrel\signtool.exe sign /a /f PersonalCodeSigningCertificate.pfx /p ******** /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256
```

If i run the exact call the signing works with no problem :-/

Any Idea what that could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be that the Octopus Tentacle was running under *SYSTEM* which would not let me use the *signtool.exe*